# 2 JSON Curl Requests in a PHP file in sequence?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have PHP code to execute 2 Curl calls to the same URL with different data. It works but there is some lag (a few seconds) between the first and the 2nd.
i have looked at curl multi but cannot figure out how to use it for JSON arrays.
please help?

```
<?php
$data = array("epic" => $epic, "expiry" => "DFB");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$headers = array(
'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'X-IG-API-KEY: '.$xapikey,
'Version: 1',
'X-SECURITY-TOKEN: '.$_SESSION['api_xtoken'],
'CST: ' .$_SESSION['api_cst'],
'_method: DELETE',

);
$ch = curl_init('' . $trading_url . '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

    
$data2 = array("currencyCode" => "GBP", "direction" => $tv_direction);
$data_string2 = json_encode($data2);


$ch2 = curl_init('' . $trading_url . '');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string2);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers2);

$result2 = curl_exec($ch2);
```

Comment: IMO, you should put the curl request in a method or function and call it 2 times with different params.

Comment: Since the two don't seem to depend on each other, using parallel requests should work. Can you show how you tried it? That said, careful reading of the docs is required. The lack of `curl_close` indicates you need some work in that area.

Comment: @nice_dev How would that help?

Comment: @Misunderstood Making a method would ensure consistency in opening and closing of curl connections. OP could also improvise it to make curl resource persist across multiple calls.

Comment: i have added a close and put it into a function and call it twice, however its still takes 5 seconds which is quite long. I was looking for a way to speed up 2 curl requests by using curl_multi but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening curl connection two times also you have not closed the connection once the request has been completed you need to close the connection

can try something like this

```
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$headers = array(
'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'X-IG-API-KEY: '.$xapikey,
'Version: 1',
'X-SECURITY-TOKEN: '.$_SESSION['api_xtoken'],
'CST: ' .$_SESSION['api_cst'],
'_method: DELETE',

);
$ch = curl_init('' . $trading_url . '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

    
$data2 = array("currencyCode" => "GBP", "direction" => $tv_direction);
$data_string2 = json_encode($data2);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers2);

$result2 = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start them simultaneously using `stream_socket_client()`
You can also use stream_socket_client() to make calls to two of your own php scripts where each of your curl requests are in each script.
You then call your two scripts using `stream_socket_client()` where the urls used are to your own scripts.

It's not simple to use sockets, so I included some code I wrote 10 years ago.  As I remember it took a day or two to get it working

What this script does is validate webpages using the W3C CSS and HTML validator tools and webpage speed test to evaluate how well a webpage was designed.  Calling them in parallel reduced the time significantly vs making the requests serially. 
You may want to use a newer user agent.

```
  ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0');
  set_time_limit (60);
  $timeout = 120; 
  $result = array(); 
  $sockets = array(); 
  $buffer_size = 8192;
  $id = 0;
  $urls = array();
  $path = $url;
  $url = urlencode("$url");
  $urls[] = array('host' => "jigsaw.w3.org",'path' => "/css-validator/validator?uri=$url&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=no&lang=en&output=text");
  $urls[] = array('host' => "validator.w3.org",'path' => "/check?uri=$url&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&output=json");
  $urls[] = array('host' => "validator.w3.org",'path' => "/check?uri=$url&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=XHTML+Basic+1.1&group=0&output=json");
  $urls[] = array('host' => "www.webpagetest.org",'path' => "/runtest.php?f=xml&bwDown=10000&bwUp=1500&latency=40&fvonly=1&k=1a736137bdd4ea914a6fc7ca06f71a&url=$url");
  $err = '';
  foreach($urls as $path){
    $host = $path['host'];
    $path = $path['path'];
    $http = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\n\r\n";
  //  echo "<br/>\n=>$host<br/>\n=>$path<br/>\n=>$http<br/>\n";
    $stream = stream_socket_client("$host:80", $errno,$errstr, 120,STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT); 
    if ($stream) {
      $sockets[] = $stream;  // supports multiple sockets
      $start[] = microtime(true);
      fwrite($stream, $http);
    }
    else { 
   $err .=  "$id Failed<br>\n";
    }
  }

while (count($sockets)) {
  $read = $sockets; 
  stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, $timeout);
  if (count($read)) {
    foreach ($read as $r) { 
      $id = array_search($r, $sockets); 
      $data = fread($r, $buffer_size); 
      if (strlen($data) == 0) { 
     //   echo "$id Closed: " . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
        $closed[$id] = microtime(true);
        fclose($r); 
        unset($sockets[$id]);
      } 
      else {
        $result[$id] .= $data; 
      }
    }
  }
  else { 
 //   echo 'Timeout: ' . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works but the only problem is that i am using an API and sometimes the API reports an error as i need the curl requests to work in sequence. I have decided just to make a function, use curl close and call it twice. thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome.  stream_socket_client() is a great way to do multi-tasking in PHP.